# If : $\binom{p-1}{k} \equiv (-1)^k \pmod p$ for all $k$ then $p$ is a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime, and let $1 \leq k \leq p - 1$ be an integer then :
>
> $\binom{p-1}{k} \equiv (-1)^k \pmod p$

Proof :

Because $\binom{p-1}{k}=\frac{(p-1)(p-2)\cdots (p-k)}{k!}$ is an integer and $\gcd(k!,p)=1$

it sufficies to show that :

$(p-1)(p-2)\cdots (p-k) \equiv (-1)^k \cdot k! \pmod p$

which is evident .

> **Conjecture :**
>
> Let $k$ and $p$ be a positive integers such that : $p>4$ and $k\in [1,p-1]$
>
> If : $\binom{p-1}{k} \equiv (-1)^k \pmod p$ for all $k$ then $p$ is a prime number .

I wrote Maple program . The statement is true up to $p=1500$ , and I guess that there is no counterexample at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, something stronger is true, in that requiring the condition for *all* the $k$ in $[1,p]$ is overkill:  Suppose $\binom{p-1}{k}\equiv (-1)^k\pmod{p}$ for all $1\leq k\leq \lfloor\sqrt{p}\rfloor$.  Then for each such $k$,
$$
\binom{p}{k}=\binom{p-1}{k}+\binom{p-1}{k-1}\equiv (-1)^k+(-1)^{k-1}\equiv 0\pmod{p}.
$$
But if $p$ is composite, this fails when $k$ is the smallest prime factor of $p$, which is guaranteed to be between $1$ and $\lfloor\sqrt{p}\rfloor$.

---

Edit to add proof of the last claim:  Let $q$ be the smallest factor of $p$, and write $p=qr$.  Then
$$
\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p!}{q!(p-q)!}=\frac{r(p-1)(p-2)\cdots(p-q+1)}{(q-1)!},
$$
the numerator of which is not divisible by $p=qr$ since $q\nmid (p-1)(p-2)\cdots(p-q+1)$.

Comment: Do you mean $p$ in place of $n$ in the last statement? The $n$ comes out of nowhere...

Comment: Yup, great, thanks.

Comment: @CamMcLeman,Can we prove stronger case when $k \in [1,\lfloor \sqrt p \rfloor ]$ ? What do you think ?

Comment: Yup.  In fact, let me edit the answer directly, since that thought occurred to me while writing it up.

Comment: I have edit your answer to fix small typo ...

Answer (score 3):

**HINT** $\rm\ \ mod\ p\!:\ {p-1\choose k}\equiv (-1)^k\ \iff\ (1 + x)^p\ \equiv \ 1 + x^p\ \ $ since

$$\rm (1+x)^{p-1}\ =\ \sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{p-1}\ {p-1\choose k}\ x^k\ \equiv \ \sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{p-1}\ (-x)^k\ \equiv\ \frac{1-(-x)^p}{1+x} $$

Comment: the "freshman dream" theorem says :" If $p$ is a prime number then $(x+y)^p \equiv x^p+y^p \pmod p$ ", but not vice versa .

Comment: @pedja The primality test $\rm\ n\:$ is prime $\rm\iff (1+x)^n \:\equiv\ 1 + x^n\pmod n\:,\:$ is well-known and easily proved, e.g. see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) on the AKS primality test. Your exercise is an equivalent form of this primality test, stating the polynomial equality in terms of the coefficients.

Comment: ,I see,you are right..I wrote primality test based on this conjecture but it runs in exponential time...

Comment: @pedja One way to optimize it to polynomial time is to proceed as in the AKS primality test.

Comment: ,Maybe there is some other way of optimization besides AKS method...